# Flutter file picker unexpected null value

Tags: image, flutter, file-upload

id love your support on this one.
The thing is that im trying to upload a file to firebase useing file-picker with flutter.
This is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:hire_me/firebase/firebaseApi.dart';
import 'package:hire_me/buttonWidget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class ImageUploader extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageUploader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageUploaderState createState() => _ImageUploaderState();
}

class _ImageUploaderState extends State<ImageUploader> {
  UploadTask? task;
  File? file;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fileName =
        file != null ? basename(file!.path) : 'No File Selected Yet';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Upload Image'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ButtonWidget(
                icon: Icons.attach_file,
                text: 'Select File',
                onClicked: selectFile,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Text(fileName,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              SizedBox(
                height: 48,
              ),
              ButtonWidget(
                  icon: Icons.cloud_upload_outlined,
                  text: 'Upload File',
                  onClicked: uploadFile)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future selectFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    if (result != null) {
      final path = result.files.single.path!;

      setState(() => file = File(path));
    }
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    if (file == null) return;

    final fileName = basename(file!.path);
    final destination = 'files/$fileName';

    FirebaseApi.uploadFile(destination, file!);
    setState(() {});

    if (task == null) return;

    final snapshot = await task!.whenComplete(() => {});
    final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    print('Download Link: $urlDownload');
  }
}
```

[image: screen where i upload the file]

When i click on the upload file button, it opens the platform file picker and after selecting an image i get the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected null value.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:5037:11)
    at Object.nullCheck (http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:5362:30)
    at imageUploader._ImageUploaderState.new.selectFile
    (http://localhost:51207/packages/hire_me/screens/imageUploader.dart.lib.js:417:27)
    at selectFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:37374:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:37245:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:32501:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:33028:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:33066:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:32914:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:32935:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:37497:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:37503:13)
    at http://localhost:51207/dart_sdk.js:33274:9
```

I have tested this on chrome and android.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In this case, your variable that you have made-

```
UploadTask? task;
File? file;
```

you have to assign these variables. This is the reason they are showing the **Unexpected null** error.

In my case I had a boolean variable, I assigned it with false ->

```
this.isActive = false,
```

So you should make a constructor for your variables. Such as:

```
    class ImageUploader extends StatefulWidget {
      UploadTask? task;
      File? file;
      const ImageUploader({Key? key, this.task, this.file}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _ImageUploaderState createState() => _ImageUploaderState();
    }
    
    class _ImageUploaderState extends State<ImageUploader> {
      
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final fileName =
            file != null ? basename(file!.path) : 'No File Selected Yet';
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('Upload Image'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ButtonWidget(
                    icon: Icons.attach_file,
                    text: 'Select File',
                    onClicked: selectFile,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                  ),
                  Text(fileName,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 48,
                  ),
                  ButtonWidget(
                      icon: Icons.cloud_upload_outlined,
                      text: 'Upload File',
                      onClicked: uploadFile)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Future selectFile() async {
        FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    
        if (result != null) {
          final path = result.files.single.path!;
    
          setState(() => file = File(path));
        }
      }
    
      Future uploadFile() async {
        if (file == null) return;
    
        final fileName = basename(file!.path);
        final destination = 'files/$fileName';
    
        FirebaseApi.uploadFile(destination, file!);
        setState(() {});
    
        if (task == null) return;
    
        final snapshot = await task!.whenComplete(() => {});
        final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    
        print('Download Link: $urlDownload');
      }
    }
```

if this still shows the **unexpected null** error, then you have to assign the variables in the constructor.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line in file picker:

```
  withData: true,
```